# Iterate over every single value in a Raster GDAL C API

Tags: gdal, c

I am learning C, and I am trying to use the C API to iterate over the values of an array. So far I've been playing around printing the projection, Width and Height of the raster, but I would like to iterate over the values of a band I am reading as an array, here is my code (modified from [enter link description here](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)

```
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h"
int main()
{

    GDALDatasetH raster;
    GDALAllRegister();
    raster = GDALOpen( "/home/roger/Documents/98_GDAL_C++_snippets/data/Isle_wight.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    if(raster==NULL)
    {
    printf("Invalid Raster Dataset");
    }
    else
    {
    GDALRasterBandH raster_band;
    int XSize, YSize;

    raster_band = GDALGetRasterBand( raster, 1);
    GDALGetBlockSize( raster_band, &XSize, &YSize);
    float *pafScanline;
    int nXSize = GDALGetRasterBandXSize (raster_band);
    int nYSize = GDALGetRasterBandYSize (raster_band);
    pafScanline = (float*) CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*nXSize);
    float band1[nXSize];
    band1 = GDALRasterIO(raster_band, 0, 0,GF_Read, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
}
}
```

In the last line: `band1 = GDALRasterIO(raster_band, 0, 0, GF_Read, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSIze, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0)`,

I receive the following message: 
`float band1[nXSize] : expression must be a modifiable value`

I guess it is because I am trying to assing what comes from GDALRasterIO to an array, I thought that is what comes from GDALRasterIO, as the documentation states:

> Reading Raster Data

There are a few ways to read raster data, but the most common is via the GDALRasterBand::RasterIO() method. This method will automatically take care of data type conversion, up/down sampling and windowing. ***The following code will read the first scanline of data into a similarly sized buffer, converting it to floating point as part of the operation***.

Is this ***first scanline of data*** an array I can iterate over? Or I am doing it in the wrong way?